# Run the stopPropagation function for my modal

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make this function work, but I can't. I would like my modal not to close when I click on the content.

HTML code:

```
<div id="modal">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Modal Window</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorem est earum illo, dignissimos cumque consequatur doloremque in? Ipsum placeat iste porro eveniet fugit consequatur magni blanditiis quod perferendis quasi!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal")

var openModal = function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    modal.classList.toggle("show")
    modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal)
}

var closeModal = function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    modal.classList.remove("show")
    modal.removeEventListener("click", closeModal)
}

document.querySelectorAll(".trigger").forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener("click", openModal)
})
```

The modal opens well, but I would like it not to close when I click on the container: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWkP6.jpg

Comment: There is no element in your HTML in your post which has class `trigger`.

Comment: In my HTML, all links with a trigger class can open a modal

Comment: @weegee No it won't. You get a `NodeList` and can use `forEach` on that.

Comment: This is not the problem, all is working currently. I just want stopPropagation when I click on the container

Comment: @We7dy The problem is that you have used `modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal)`, so using `stopPropagation` will not help. What you need is `document.addEventListener("click", closeModal)`

Comment: By the screenshot you attached seems like you're missing a close button for the modal. You can close the modal by either clicking on the close button (usually an X in the top right corner), by hitting ESC key, or by clicking outside the modal. So the problem is with your implementation.

Comment: That's not really the problem. I'm just working on it, but the problem is that I don't want to close my modal box if I click inside it.

Comment: inside the `openModal` function, this line `modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal)` makes it so that when you click on the modal it closes the event, since you're adding another event handler which fires on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing so:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal")

var openModal = function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault()
    modal.classList.toggle("show")
    modal.addEventListener("click", closeModal)
    modal.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", stopPropagation)
}

var closeModal = function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault()
    modal.classList.remove("show")
    modal.removeEventListener("click", closeModal)
    modal.querySelector(".container").removeEventListener("click", stopPropagation)
}

var stopPropagation = function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation()
}

document.querySelectorAll(".trigger").forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener("click", openModal)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First assign the event listener to the document like

```
document.addEventListener("click", closeModal)
```

Check if the target element is not your modal like

```
if(!document.getElementById('modal').contains(event.target)) {
   // the place where you clicked it not #modal
   // hide the modal
}
```

Implementation

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal")

var openModal = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  modal.style.display = "block"
  document.addEventListener("click", closeModal)
}

var closeModal = function(event) {
  if(!document.getElementById('modal').contains(event.target)) {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    modal.style.display = 'none'
    modal.removeEventListener("click", closeModal)
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".trigger").forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener("click", openModal)
})
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:none;
  background:white;
}
html{height:100%;background:red;}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Modal Window</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsa dolorem est earum illo, dignissimos cumque consequatur doloremque in? Ipsum placeat iste porro eveniet fugit consequatur magni blanditiis quod perferendis quasi!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="trigger">Open Modal<a>
```